# Node Path Normalise trailing periods .. and

Tags: node.js

Can anyone explain to me why this holds true:

> Normalize a string path, taking care of '..' and '.' parts.
>
> When multiple slashes are found, they're replaced by a single one;
>   when the path contains a trailing slash, it is preserved. On Windows
>   backslashes are used.

```
Example: 
path.normalize('/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..') 
// returns '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
```

When I would expect it to return

```
'/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux'
```

This is from the Node Documentation
http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p

**Edit**

After running some test I know "why" this is happening, but do not understand the logic behind it.
Below are three examples with their input and output.

```
/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..      /foo/bar//baz/asdf
/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/.       /foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux
/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/        /foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/
```

So for the original I can see that the double period ".." removed the final folder and the single period "." removes the trailing slash. I understand that when including files in parental folders you would prefix a path with ../ I am assuming that you can actually place this anywhere within a path, although there seems little point to me currently to be able to place it say mid path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double colon (`..`) means the parent directory as is standard in Linux. So, `/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux/..` basically selects the parent directory of `/foo/bar//baz/asdf/quux`